# Upgrading an old laptop (windows 7) with network issues

Tags: windows-7, networking, formatting

I tried to update an old Dell XPS 15" from 2011 with Windows 7 installed.

First I tried to install the updates but I always had network errors like *"The updates can't be downloaded"*

I try to use the `ping` command and it worked.

But when I tried to load a web page I had again a network error.

After I tried to boot into safe mode and I managed to load some websites (but this mode prevents to update Windows)

Do you have any suggestions ? Why can't I load web pages ? It's like a port is blocked by a software, I don't know...

Comment: Please include in your post the error code mentioned in the error message. The code should have 8 letters and look like "8024402F" or be prefaced by "0x" such as "0x8024402F".

Comment: @harrymc the error is 80072EE2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I always had network errors like "The updates can't be downloaded"

> when I tried to load a web page I had again a network error.

Try reinitialising the network states. Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear answer and sorry for the deadline for response. I executed your commands. Now (without booting in safe mode) I have, sometimes, 200 http code when I load some web page and some time some "timeout error". Moreover when I use the "windows 10 update assistant", the client is not enable to download anything...

Comment: @AdrienG It's working now?

Comment: From the comment on my answer, it seems that the poster decided to reformat and install Windows 10. So this post has no clear solution.

Comment: @harrymc the DavidPostill's answer helped me to browse some websites I couldn't reach before. So we can consider his answer as a solution :)

Comment: This was just an informative note for DavidPostill.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like some installed product is blocking your access to some websites.

The likeliest product is your security software or anti-virus.
Try to disable them and check again.

You may use Safe Mode with Network to update the computer.

You could also power-cycle your router to verify if it is the source of
the problem .

Comment: Thank for your answer. I decided to format the hard drive to W10 ;)